# Linux recursive copy files to its parent folder

Tags: linux, bash

I want to copy recursively files to its parent folder for a specific file extension. For example:

```
./folderA/folder1/*.txt to ./folderA/*.txt  
./folderB/folder2/*.txt to ./folderB/*.txt
```

etc.

I checked `cp` and `find` commands but couldn't get it working.

Comment: You may try `mv */* .`

Comment: I'm prone to say that this should go into [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). An answer to your question is probably `rsync(1)`, though.

Comment: @SamiLaine could you spare a bit more details please? :)

Comment: Do you always have two levels of directories?  What do you want to happen to a file in `folderA`?  Should it stay there or be moved to `.`?  What should happen if `folder1` contains further sub-directories? Also, I'm uncertain whether you mean to *move* or to *copy* the files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect that while you say *copy*, you actually mean to *move* the files up to their respective parent directories.  It can be done easily using `find`:

```bash
$ find . -name '*.txt' -type f -execdir mv -n '{}' ../ \;
```

The above command recurses into the current directory `.` and then applies the following cascade of conditionals to each item found:

1. `-name '*.txt'` will filter out only files that have the `.txt` extension
2. `-type f` will filter out only regular files (eg, not directories that – for whatever reason – happen to have a name ending in `.txt`)
3. `-execdir mv -n '{}' ../ \;` executes the command `mv -n '{}' ../` *in the containing directory* where the `{}` is a placeholder for the matched file's name and the single quotes are needed to stop the shell from interpreting the curly braces.  The `;` terminates the command and again has to be escaped from the shell interpreting it.

I have passed the `-n` flag to the `mv` program to avoid accidentally overwriting an existing file.

The above command will transform the following file system tree

```
dir1/
    dir11/
        file3.txt
        file4.txt
    dir12/
    file2.txt
dir2/
    dir21/
        file6.dat
    dir22/
        dir221/
        dir221/file8.txt
        file7.txt
    file5.txt
dir3/
    file9.dat
file1.txt
```

into this one:

```
dir1/
    dir11/
    dir12/
    file3.txt
    file4.txt
dir2/
    dir21/
        file6.dat
    dir22/
        dir221/
        file8.txt
    file7.txt
dir3/
    file9.dat
file2.txt
file5.txt
```

To get rid of the empty directories, run

```bash
$ find . -type d -empty -delete
```

Again, this command will traverse the current directory `.` and then apply the following:

1. `-type d` this time filters out only directories
2. `-empty` filters out only those that are empty
3. `-delete` deletes them.

**Fine print:** `-execdir` is not specified by POSIX, though major implementations (at least the GNU and BSD one) support it.  If you need strict POSIX compliance, you'll have to make do with the less safe `-exec` which would need additional thought to be applied correctly in this case.

Finally, please try your commands in a test directory with dummy files, not your actual data.  Especially with the `-delete` option of `find`, you can loose all your data quicker than you might imaging.  Read [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) and, if that is not enough, the [reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html) of `find`.  Never blindly copy shell commands from random strangers posted on the internet if you don't understand them.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say that `-execdir` is a GNU extension: [`-execdir` exists for BSD find](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?find%281%29).

Comment: OMG, thank you so much, it worked perfectly. I lost so much time trying to figure it out. :))

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Thanks, that's good to know.  But in the POSIX specification of `find`, there is no `-execdir`, so we cannot use it in scripts that need to be portable.

Comment: Sure. Just replace your GNU statement (which is false) and instead write that `-execdir` is not specified by POSIX. It'll then be correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
$cp ./folderA/folder1/*.txt ./folderA
```

Try this commnad

Comment: missing . before `/folderA`

Comment: #fejese yep it should be there

Comment: Not really my solution. It will only worl for folderA. I need a solution that will copy file to its direct parent folder. It should also work for folderA and folderB and all of it's subfolders simultaneously. Thanks

Comment: No, still not what I wanted. Probably due to my poor English skills. This solution will work only for folder1 files, not folderA subfolders and folderB too.

Answer (score 0):

Run something like this from the root(ish) directory:

```
#! /bin/bash
BASE_DIR=./

new_dir() {
LOC_DIR=`pwd`
for i in "${LOC_DIR}"/*; do
    [[ -f "${i}" ]] && cp "${i}" ../
    [[ -d "${i}" ]] && cd "${i}" && new_dir
cd ..
done
return 0
}

new_dir
```

This will search each directory.  When a file is encountered, it copies the file up a directory.  When a directory is found, it will move down into the directory and start the process over again.  I think it'll work for you.

Good luck.